# Some application of Strong maximum principle.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, maximum-principle

> Strong Maximum Principle
>
> Let $\Omega$ be an open connected bounded set. Suppose $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\bar \Omega)$ satisfies
>
> $$\Delta u + c(x) u\geq0$$
> where $c\in C(\Omega)$ and $c(x) \leq 0$, for all $x\in \Omega$. Suppose $M:=\sup\{u(x),x\in \Omega\} > 0.$ Then $u$ has maximum on boundary of $\Omega$.

My problem is

> Let $\Omega=(0,1)^2$. Suppose $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\bar \Omega)$ satisfies
> $$\Delta u - u^3=0 \mbox{ in $\Omega$ }$$ $$u(x,1)=0,u(x,0)=1$$
> Show that $u$ is unique and $0\leq u \leq 1$.

My try :

Let $u_1,u_2$ be solutions of this equation.

Let $w=u_1-u_2$
By easy calculation,

$$\Delta w -(w^2+3u_1u_2)w=0$$
and
$$c=-(w^2+3u_1u_2) \leq 0$$

so

$$\Delta w +cw \geq 0$$
$$w(x,1)=0,w(x,0)=0$$

I think I can use Strong Maximum Principle.

But I think I need some conditions
$$ w(0,y)=w(1,y) =0$$

If this conditions is satisfied, I'm done.

Do you think given conditions in this problem are sufficient to solve it?

Comment: It seems to me you need to specify $u(0, y)$ and $u(1, y)$ as you have $u(x, 0)$ and $u(x, 1)$.  Otherwise I'm doubful that the "given conditions in this problem are sufficient to solve it".  Thanks.